# Prestashop subdomain development server

Tags: subdomain, admin, development-environment, prestashop-1.6

I'm new to prestashop and I am trying to set up a development version of a prestashop site I have inherited but am having a few issues. In our site https://www.rawlinspaints.com, I have set up the subdomain of dev.rawlinspaints.com and created a copy of the db and linked the dev site to the new db and copied all the files across to the dev site.

The dev site loads, but doesn't render any images and the css and js are not loading. I also cannot access the admin for the site either. How would I remedy these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clone a Prestashop instance, you need to manually edit the value of `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` in the `ps_configuration` table to match your current URL.

Comment: I have made all these changes and that is why the dev site loads up, but the admin just loops back to the homepage

Comment: I have the frontend all sorted out now by disabling ssl in the ps_configuration table but I cannot access the back office, it just reloads the home page. Is there somewhere other than ps_configuration table that the back office is configured?

Comment: Try to disable the .htaccess file to see if there is a nasty redirect rule out there

Comment: when you say disable do you mean delete?

Comment: Yep. Or rename it (better to rename it...).

Comment: that just caused the site to bring up a 500 internal error

Comment: did you rename the root .htaccess file or the one in admin dir ?

Comment: there isnt one in the admin folder

Comment: when I set define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);  in the defines.inc.php  I get this error 'Chose Module is not a valid module name'. at the bottom of the page

Comment: have a look in the modules directory, if there is a folder named 'chose module' you need to delete it

Comment: there is no module called chose or anything like that

Comment: this what this error message means. It can be any module with a wrong class name. I would perform a search on modules folder for 'chose' in all php files content

Comment: in both posstaticblocks and posstaticfooter I found this line, $arrayModule[0] = array('id_module'=>0, 'name'=>'Chose Module'); any ideas?

Comment: Prestashop modules name MUST be lowercase and without whitespace.

Comment: However, it is unlikely the root cause of your issue. This is probably just a warning